# Getting issue while trying to convert a list to a dictionary in python but it's extracting only the last key-value pair from the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My list look something like this,

```
[' Objective ',
 ' To get an opportunity where I can make the best of my potential.',
' Experience ',
 ' Division of Cranes Software International Ltd . Project title November-2021 • Each Differentiation using Iris Flower UNDERGRADUATE PROJECT']
```

P.s. the length of list is 101

And I'm trying to convert this list to a dict

```
col_dict = {}
for i in range(1, len(columns_lst),2):
    col_dict = {columns_lst[i] : columns_lst[i+1]}
    col_dict[columns_lst[i]] = columns_lst[i + 1]
```

But it's storing only the last key and value pair in `col_dict` and not the whole data of the list. Please help me understand why is this happening and how to resolved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way to achieve the output is:

```
# l = [' Objective ', ' To get... ]

out = {l[2*i]: l[2*i+1] for i in range(len(l)//2)}

# or
# out  = {l[i]: l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}
```

Or on python ≥ 3.10, use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise

out = dict(pairwise(l))
```

output:

```
{' Objective ': ' To get an opportunity where I can make the best of my potential.',
 ' Experience ': ' Division of Cranes Software International Ltd . Project title November-2021 • Each Differentiation using Iris Flower UNDERGRADUATE PROJECT'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a brand new dictionary in every iteration. Remove

```
 col_dict = {columns_lst[i] : columns_lst[i+1]}
```

Also since you're iterating over the length of the list and looking forward, the last index `i` can take is `len(columns_lst)-2` since the last index is `len(columns_lst)-1` (which `i+1` takes). So your code should be

```
for i in range(0, len(columns_lst)-1, 2):
    col_dict[columns_lst[i]] = columns_lst[i + 1]
```

Another way is to use `zip` so that you can walk the items at even numbered indexes and items at odd-numbered indexes together:

```
col_dict = {i:j for i, j in zip(columns_lst[::2], columns_lst[1::2])}
```

Output:

```
{' Objective ': ' To get an opportunity where I can make the best of my potential.',
 ' Experience ': ' Division of Cranes Software International Ltd . Project title November-2021 • Each Differentiation using Iris Flower UNDERGRADUATE PROJECT'}
```